# Css trick to conjoin divs

Tags: css, html

Is there a way we could conjoin three divs together?

```
Hello
<div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="LeftDiv"></div>
    <div class="CenterDiv">
        <input id="txtTest" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="RightDiv"></div>
</div>
World!
```

what we need here is to present the code this way:

`Hello<*LeftDiv*><*CenterDiv with the textbox*><*RightDiv*>World`

I tried to use float:left on LeftDiv, CenterDiv and RightDiv but the css also affects the mainContainer. I also need to set the LeftDiv's and RightDiv's **height and width** on the css but I just can't do it without the float.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added question -  when LeftDiv, CenterDiv and RightDiv are floated-left, why is mainContainer affected? i just want to have the three inner divs conjoined without affecting the parent div's behavior...

---

divs with display: inline-block dont work as expected.
But spans do.

```
Hello
<span class="mainContainer">
    <span class="LeftDiv"></span><span class="CenterDiv">
        <input id="txtTest" type="text"/>
    </span><span class="RightDiv"></span>
</span>
World!
```

And the spans should also not have a space between them because most browsers would render them with a white space in between... =)

*(Answered for future reference)*

Comment: both LeftDiv and RightDiv are intentionally left empty so i could just use a background image for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use display inline-block, that way there will be no "linebreak" before divs

```
div.mainContainer, div.mainContainer div
{
  display:-moz-inline-stack; /* for gecko */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

try `goog-inline-block` class defined in [goog/demos/css/common.css](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/css/common.css) of closure library - supposedly covers all major browsers

Comment: inline-block is not implemented on older browsers... =(

Comment: hmm, you're right... I've just searched and found something on the subject.

Comment: divs are not compatible with display: inline-block but this answer helps. =)

Answer (score 0):

You could float all the child divs of "mainContainer" left like below, then you can set height and width requirements as you please.

```
#mainContainer > div
{
    float:left;
}
#LeftDiv
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
#RightDiv
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Hmm, and if your left and right containers are only meant for a background image, you might consider just making it one image and applying it to mainContainer,

```
#mainContainer
{
    background-image:url(theimage.jpg);
    padding-left:100px; /*The amount of the image to the left */
    padding-right:100px; /* the amount of the image to the right. */
}
```

Comment: I can't use float: left because that would render the code:
<*LeftDiv*><*CenterDiv with the textbox*><*RightDiv*>Hello World. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It shouldn't as long as it is wrapped in mainContainer.

Comment: the two empty divs really need to be added because the background image of LeftDiv is like "(" and RightDiv's is like a ")"; What i expect the code to render is "(textbox)"; and the whole is expected to show Hello(textbox)World... =(